# Como passar variáveis do C# MVC 4 para SCSS do SASS?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, sass

Preciso alterar meus arquivos CSS dinamicamente puxando alguns dados ,como cores, do banco.
Optei por utilizar SASS na aplicação, mas eu consigo importar uma variável da aplicação em MVC 4 para o meu arquivo SCSS ?

Comment: poderia dar um exemplo melhor? o seu codigo? posso tentar ajudar.

Answer (score 1):

Você consegue até usar eval para processar expressões javascript, mas não dá pra criar valores dinâmicos desta forma que você deseja em SASS.
O que você pode fazer é criar múltiplos arquivos de estilo e carregá-los dinamicamente (ou usar Themes) de acordo com o conteúdo do que você recuperou do banco de dados.